# HOC Higher-Order Components how to pass parameters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

my component App

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import City from "./City";
import withDataLoader from "./withDataLoader";

const App = () => {
  const MyCity = withDataLoader(
     City,
    "https://5e5cf5eb97d2ea0014796f01.mockapi.io/api/v1/cities/1"
   );

  return (
    <div className="page">
      <MyCity />
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

my Higher-Order Components

```
import React from "react";
import Spinner from "./Spiner";

const withDataLoader = (url, Component) => {
   class Container extends React.Component {

    state = "";

    componentDidMount() {
      this.get();
    }

    get = () => {
      fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => this.setState(data));
    };

    render() {
      return this.state === "" ? <Spinner /> : <Component data={this.state} />;
    }
  };
  return Container
};

export default withDataLoader;
```

I pass parameters to HOC

```
withDataLoader(url, City)
```

but in the documentation I saw another  entry
`withDataLoader(url)(City)` https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-component...
how to make it so that you can pass parameters to the hock so withDataLoader(url)(City)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing from `withDataLoader(url, City)` to `withDataLoader(url)(City)` called [currying](https://javascript.info/currying-partials).

```
// Change function declaration
const withDataLoader = (url, Component) => {}
|
v
const withDataLoader = (url) => (Component) => {}
```

And note that you might have a missplaced values in function call:

```
// Instead (City,URL)
const MyCity = withDataLoader("https://...",City)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I solved the problem this way
const withDataLoader = (url) => {
  return function (Component) {
    return class Container extends React.Component {
      state = "";
      componentDidMount() {
        this.get();
      }

      get = () => {
        fetch(url)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => this.setState(data));
      };

      render() {
        return this.state === "" ? (
          <Spinner />
        ) : (
          <Component data={this.state} />
        );
      }
    };
  };
};
```